# All integer points on a line segment

Tags: python, range, tuples

I'm looking for a short smart way to find all integer points on a line segment. The 2 points are also integers, and the line can be at an angle of 0,45,90,135 etc. degrees.

Here is my long code(so far the 90 degree cases):

```
def getPoints(p1,p2)
if p1[0] == p2[0]:
    if p1[1] < p2[1]:
        return [(p1[0],x) for x in range(p1[1],p2[1])]
    else:
        return [(p1[0],x) for x in range(p1[1],p2[1],-1)]
if p2[1] == p2[1]:
    if p1[0] < p2[0]:
        return [(x,p1[1]) for x in range(p1[0],p2[0])]
    else:
        return [(x,p1[1]) for x in range(p1[0],p2[0],-1)]
```

EDIT: I haven't mentioned it clear enough, but the slope will always be an integer -1, 0 or 1, there are 8 cases that are need to be checked.

Comment: Please clarify - how is a line specified? Are we talking about y= 2x+7, or are we talking about a list of points?

Comment: points are 2 x,y tuples

Comment: You're talking about a line *segment*.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham_line_algorithm)? It uses only integer addition, subtraction, and bit shifting, so is very fast.

Comment: @martineau this seems like an overkill, since i'm only dealing with increments of 1, or 0, no fractions involved

Comment: @Bartlomiej: In that case you ought to be able to determine what it would do in each one of the small number of specific cases and derive something optimized for just them. Actually, the 0 and 90 degree cases are trivial leaving you with only the 45 and likely very similar 135 degree cases to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the slope to lowest terms (p/q), then step from one endpoint of the line segment to the other in increments of p vertically and q horizontally. The same code can work for vertical line segments if your reduce-to-lowest-terms code reduces 5/0 to 1/0.

Comment: can this be done with itertools or a better than mine list comprehension?

Comment: I'm not sure what the most elegant code would be. Vertical and horizontal line segments throw things off a bit; the first thing I came up with would've required special-casing those.

Comment: i could write code that works, but the amount of repeating code is throwing me off, that's why i turned to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Do a little bit of maths for each pair of points calculate m & c for mx+c and compare it to the formulae for the lines you are considering.  (N.B. You ***Will*** get some divide by zeros to cope with.)

Answer (score 0):

> i could write code that works, but the amount of repeating code is
>   throwing me off, that's why i turned to you guys

This could stand a lot of improvement but maybe it gets you on the track. 
(sorry, don't have time to make it better just now!)

```
def points(p1,p2):
  slope = (p2[1]-p1[1])/float(p2[0]-p1[0])
  [(x,x*slope) for x in range (p1[0], p2[0]) if int(x*slope) == x*slope)]
```

Comment: As I say, it's just an example to get you started and you can probably improve it. For example, you can swap p1 and p2 if p1[0]>p2[0].

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer of @Jon Kiparsky.

```
def points_on_line(p1, p2):
    fx, fy = p1 
    sx, sy = p2 
    if fx == sx and fy == sy:
        return []
    elif fx == sx:
        return [(fx, y) for y in range(fy+1, sy)]
    elif fy == sy:
        return [(x, fy) for x in range(fx+1, sx)]
    elif fx > sx and fy > sy:
        p1, p2 = p2, p1  

    slope = (p2[1] - p1[1]) / float(p2[0] - p1[0])
    return [(x, int(x*slope)) for x in range(p1[0], p2[0]) if int(x*slope) == x*slope and (x, int(x*slope)) != p1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def getpoints(p1, p2):
  # Sort both points first.
  (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = sorted([p1, p2])
  a = b = 0.0

  # Not interesting case.
  if x1 == x2:
      yield p1

  # First point is in (0, y).
  if x1 == 0.0:
      b = y1
      a = (y2 - y1) / x2
  elif x2 == 0.0:
      # Second point is in (0, y).
      b = y2
      a = (y1 - y2) / x1
  else:
      # Both points are valid.
      b = (y2 - (y1 * x2) / x1) / (1 - (x2 / x1))
      a = (y1 - b) / x1

      for x in xrange(int(x1), int(x2) + 1):
          y = a * float(x) + b
          # Delta could be increased for lower precision.
          if abs(y - round(y)) == 0:
              yield (x, y)
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Mistyped `yield` with `return`